# Why doesn't CLion link my project with OpenCV for Windows?

Tags: opencv, cmake, clion

I'm attempting to use [OpenCV for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.13/opencv-2.4.13.exe/download) as supplied by [opencv.org](http://opencv.org) in a project I'm building with [JetBrains' CLion IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion).  I've installed the opencv library and configured CLion (`set(OpenCV_DIR`) to reference the *build* directory under it, but CMake issues the warning:

```
Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has no binaries compatible with your configuration.    
You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV library.
```

I've tried some of the older distributions from opencv.org with the same results.  It appears CMake is locating the OpenCV libraries, but doesn't want to use them.  Why, and how do I get the OpenCV libraries to work under CLion?

Comment: This has been downvoted with no explanation several times.  Note that it's OK to [Answer My Own Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is, **you will probably need to build OpenCV from source in order to use it with CLion**.  But given the number and range of partially answered and unanswered questions here* and elsewhere on using [JetBrains' CLion IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion) with [the OpenCV library](http://opencv.org), I think an overview is needed (my notes are from CLion 2016.3 and OpenCV 3.1, YMMV):

- Though not produced by JetBrains, [CMake](https://cmake.org) is very central to CLion's operation.  Understanding CMake therefore helps greatly in diagnosing CLion build problems.  In particular CMake maintains a disk "cache" of settings which you may need to clear to incorporate changes to your environment (*Tools->CMake->Reset Cache and Reload Project*).
- To make use of *OpenCV* in your build you must specify it in your project's *CMakeLists.txt* file.  You request that CMake locate your OpenCV location and link it to your `TARGET`.  An example of a sequence of commands from `CMakeLists.txt` for an executable named `mushroom` follows:

  `add_executable(mushroom ${SOURCE_FILES})
  FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mushroom ${OpenCV_LIBS})`

  (For more on `FIND_PACKAGE`, see [CMake:How To Find Libraries](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries).)
- `FIND_PACKAGE` for package *XXX* works either by way of *FindXXX.cmake* files located at CMake's `Modules` directory, or by consulting environment variable *XXXX_DIR*.  On my system, no *FindOpenCV.cmake* file was present, so I relied on the *OpenCV_DIR* environment variable instead.  This must be set, not to the root of your OpenCV installation, but to the *build* folder beneath it.  I used an entry in *CMakeLists.txt* to set this variable, e.g.:

  ```
  set(OpenCV_DIR C:/Users/myacct/AppData/Local/opencv-3.0.0/build)
  ```
- To link with OpenCV, CMake uses either *FindOpenCV.cmake* or *OpenCV_DIR* (see previous point above) to locate a file named *OpenCVConfig.cmake*.  This file is generated by and ships with a particular build of OpenCV in order to document what components are present and where they are located.
- ***Problems may occur when variable names used by OpenCVConfig.cmake conflict with those CLion has stored in its environment***. In particular, if your OpenCV was built by Microsoft Visual C (*MSVC*), as is [the Windows distribution from opencv.org](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/), it won't work with CLion.

  Because CLion's build toolchain (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>-toolchain) uses either MinGW or Cygwin, *OpenCVConfig.cmake* will search for OpenCV binaries under a subdirectory named *mingw* or *cygwin* ***and will find none*** because the binaries were built with MSVC (it will look in a directory like *vc11* or *vc12* instead).  This probably means ***you will need to build OpenCV from source in order to use it with CLion***.

  *Would reconfiguring OpenCVConfig.cmake to point to the MSVC binaries make this work?* you may ask.  Unfortunately the answer is still no, because [libraries built with one compiler typically cannot be linked with another one](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands).
- *OpenCVConfig.cmake* or *FindOpenCV.cmake* likely contain diagnostic messages, but when CLion executes CMake for you, `message(STATUS)` calls are not displayed.  To make them display, change them to `message(WARNING)` or `message(FATAL_ERROR)`.  *But CLion 2016.3 EAP relieves this problem; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39398373/5025060.*
- CLion does not indicate which .cmake script issued which diagnostics; don't assume they all come from the same script.

Hopefully this provides some general guidance on resolving *CLion / CMake / OpenCV* compatibility problems.  Note that this does not cover *compiler* or *linker* issues; these will not appear until *CMake* completes its initial makefile build.  Compiler or linker issues occur at a later stage and are controlled by `include*()`, `link*()` and other commands in *CMakeLists.txt*.

*Some related SO questions:
    [OpenCV Windows setup with CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36167878/5025060)
    [OpenCV CLion (Cmake) linking issue - cmake reports a strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32407200/5025060)
    [use OpenCV with Clion IDE on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35984678/5025060)
    [Compiling OpenCV on Windows with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36374039/5025060)
    [Could not find module FindOpenCV.cmake ( Error in configuration process)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8711109/5025060)
    [CMake: Of what use is find_package() if you need to specify CMAKE_MODULE_PATH anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20746936/5025060)

Comment: Clion now support MSVC toolchain in that case will it work if I use clion with MSVC toolchain for opencv build following this guide https://jamesbowley.co.uk/build-compile-opencv-3-4-in-windows-with-cuda-9-0-and-intel-mkl-tbb/?

Comment: @SaintTail, sorry, I don't know the answer to your question, but **thank you for updating us on changes to CLion.**  In particular, the information at [Ability to open a single file or folder in CLion, with other new CMake actions](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/01/clion-starts-2018-1-eap-wsl-cpp17-cmake/#cmake) indicates that some of the issues I describe in this answer are getting addressed, e.g.: *The process of decoupling CMake from CLion has started....*  If you do get CLion working as you describe, please let us know here!

Comment: It is working! I successfully make it work using msvc toolchain